# Pyqt GUI, Lineedit, Game MasterMind

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pycharm

Good day, I can not run the following code in pyqt, I'm new and do not really understand the class, I appreciate the collaboration

Apparently the problem is how to connect the function (self.ui.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect (self.checkText)

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from mastermind import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import random
import time



class Menu_mm(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MasterMind()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.comboBox.addItem("Facil")
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem("Dificil")
        self.ui.comboBox.addItem("Legendario")
        self.ui.comboBox.activated.connect(self.num)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Empezar)
        self.ui.label_14.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.label_19.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.label_20.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.label_15.setVisible(False)
        self.ui.label_16.setVisible(False)



    def num(self):
        x= self.ui.comboBox.currentText()

        if x == "Facil":
             self.ui.label_6.setText("3")
             y=1
        elif x == "Dificil":
             self.ui.label_6.setText("4")
             y=2
        else:
             self.ui.label_6.setText("5")
             y=3

    def Empezar(self):
        x = self.ui.comboBox.currentText()

        if x == "Facil":
            y = 1
        elif x == "Dificil":
            y = 2
        else:
            y = 3

        continuar = 1

        while continuar == 1:


            if y == 1:
                cant_digitos = 3
            elif y == 2:
                cant_digitos = 4
            elif y == 3:
                cant_digitos = 5
            print(cant_digitos)

            #print("cant_digitos")

            digitos = ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
            codigo = ''

            for i in range(cant_digitos):
                elegido = random.choice(digitos)
                while elegido in codigo:
                    elegido = random.choice(digitos)
                codigo = codigo + elegido
            print(codigo)

            global propuesta
            propuesta = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()


            intentos = 1


            while propuesta != codigo:
                intentos = intentos + 1
                aciertos = 0
                coincidencias = 0
                for i in range(cant_digitos):
                    if propuesta[i] == codigo[i]:
                        aciertos = aciertos + 1
                    elif propuesta[i] in codigo:
                        coincidencias = coincidencias + 1



                propuesta=self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()

                self.ui.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(self.checkText)


                print(propuesta)
                self.ui.label_13.setText(str(propuesta))
                self.ui.label_9.setText(str(aciertos))
                self.ui.label_11.setText(str(coincidencias))

            self.ui.label_14.setVisible(True)
            self.ui.label_15.setVisible(True)
            self.ui.label_16.setVisible(True)



    def checkText(self):
        propuesta =self.ui.lineEdit_2.Text()
        print("si")
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Menu_mm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why can't you run it? Provide us with the error you receive. Btw, please change the title of your question to something meaningful that describes your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your cooperation, the big problem is that the loop keeps running and will not let me enter a new entry into the lineEdit_2.

Comment: Hm, well this is because you have an infinite loop there. `continuar` is set to 1 and never changed.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, and delete this while but still does not stop.

Comment: You have a second infinite loop there: `while propuesta != codigo:`. `propuesta` is set to the content of `lineEdit_2`, but that lineEdit's content is never changed because you can't press enter on the lineEdit while the loop is blocking. Apart from that I suggest you to think through the algorithm of your program more thoroughly before coding to avoid such errors.

Comment: Eh tried to stop the loop with time.sleep () but just will not let me enter anything in the LineEdit.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the `connect` statement inside a loop.  It's going to create a new connection for each iteration through the loop

```
while continuar == 1:
    while propuesta != codigo:
        self.ui.lineEdit_2.returnPressed.connect(self.checkText)
```

You probably want to make that connection in the `__init__`

Comment: I appreciate your help, but the problem is that the loop does not stop at the lineEdit_2 to enter a new entry.